# Does applying a longer duration Charm effect extend the duration of Philter of Love's love effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, charmed

The item "Philter of Love"(DMG, p. 184) hast the following description:

> The next time you see a creature within 10 minutes after drinking this philter, you become charmed by that creature for 1 hour. If the creature is of a species and gender you are normally attracted to, you regard it as your true love **while you are charmed.**

If the creature who was the first to be seen by the creature drinking the potion charmed the drinker, would the drinker continue to regard them as their true love while they are charmed? There's no distinction that you must be charmed "in this manner" or by the effects of the potion.

So, would charming a creature affected by the Philter of Love extend the potion's love effects for the duration of the charm?

Comment: Hey, you found an actual use for Create Thrall!

Comment: @Miniman that got a chuckle out of me

Answer (score 6):

### If it did, so would any charm effect,  by any person, at any time

You are correct, the spell does not use phrasing like the *crown of madness* or *hypnotic pattern* spells do:

> [...] While the target is charmed **in this way**, a twisted crown of jagged iron appears on its head, and a madness glows in its eyes...
>
> [...] While charmed **by this spell**, the creature is incapacitated and has a speed of 0...

The text of the Philter of Love only says:

> [...] You regard it as your true love **while you are charmed**...

With a literal reading, it wouldn't matter what spell/effect charmed you, who you are charmed by, or when the charm actually happens. It only matters that you be charmed. A situation like the following would thus be possible:

1. You are in love with a Goblin due to the Philter of Love.
2. A Dwarf charms you.
3. Your charm from the Philter ends --- you are no longer charmed by the Goblin at all.
4. You are still in love with the Goblin.

Similarly you could be in love with a Goblin and then three years later that an entirely unrelated spell charms you and you would suddenly fall back in love with th Goblin.

This is absurd, and though you could stick to "RAW", this over-literal interpretation is certainly incorrect.